# How to delete a stubborn SQL 2005 Maintenance Plan

Tags: sql-server-2005

Our SQL 2005 server has a Maintenance Plan that cannot be deleted.

When I try and delete it via Management Studio I get the following error:

> An exception occurred while executing
>   a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   -> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysmaintplan_plans',
>   database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229)

Its SQL 2005 Enterprise Edition version 9.0.3042.0

I have been able to modify the plan so that it doesn't do anything, but I can't rename it or delete it.

I have a hunch that this might be something to do with Service Pack 2, as the Maintenance Plan may have been created before SP2 was applied, and I've heard some people had problems with that scenario.

edit: I am logged in as sa

Comment: What happens if you login as SA?

Comment: The same - I am already logged in as SA

Comment: What happens if you restart/reboot/re-all?

Comment: I can't reboot at will because its a production server. But this Plan has been stuck there for six months and the server has been rebooted from time to time. As the Maintenance Plan has no schedule, any resources it once had locked should have been released long ago.

Comment: Are you running Management Studio on the server itself? Or a different machine?

Comment: I was running Management Studio from a different machine. But your suggestion worked! I ran Management Studio on the server (logged in as  SA, naturally) and was able to delete the little critter.

Comment: @SqlACID - if you want to add an official answer below, I'll accept the answer so you get the appropriate pointage : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to SqlACID for the suggestion to fix this (see the question comments)

I had been using Management Studio on a separate machine.

Running Management Studio on the Server itself (and logging in as SA) allowed me to delete the stubborn Maintenance Plan.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to delete a Maintenance Plan because of a permission issue.  *"Authentication failed for user SA"* - and I was logged in as SA using Management Studio on the server.

Here is how I was able to fix the problem:

- Open the problem Maintenance Plan.
- Add a new (empty) Subplan.
- Delete the first (existing) Subplan.

As a precaution I also did this:

- Click the *Manage Connections* button.
- Click *Edit* in the Manage Connections dialog box.
- Overwrite the SA user name and password.
- Click *OK* > *Close* to get back to the Maintenance Plan.

Finally

- Save the Maintenance Plan.
- Delete the Maintenance Plan.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have success with Pete's suggestion, but I did have success following the steps here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/ae6f809f-ef74-4534-8327-b7b120a2d700/unable-to-delete-a-sql-2005-maintenance-plan

see the post by kahil kahalas:. it says:

You can also delete SQL 2005 Maintenance Plan using T - Sql.

We need to perform the below steps to delete the jobs or maintenance plans in such cases from sysmaintplan_log table or from sysmaintplan_subplans table .

Step 1: 
Execute the below query to obtain the Maintenance plan name and Id 
SELECT NAME, ID FROM MSDB..SYSMAINTPLAN_PLANS

(make sure msdb is selected for steps 2, 3 & 4)

Step 2: 
Replace the Id obtained from Step 1 into the below query and delete the entry from log table
DELETE FROM SYSMAINTPLAN_LOG WHERE PLAN_ID=' '

Step 3: 
Replace the Id obtained from Step 1 into the below query and delete the entry from subplans table as shown below,
DELETE FROM SYSMAINTPLAN_SUBPLANS WHERE PLAN_ID = ' '

Step 4: 
Finally delete the maintenance plan using the below query where ID is obtained from Step1
DELETE FROM SYSMAINTPLAN_PLANS WHERE ID = ' '

Step 5: 
Check and delete the jobs from SSMS if it exists.

(I had to go into Jobs Activity Monitor and delete it from there.)

Hope it helps u!

Kapil Khalas